# Solving a non-linear inequality involving square root

Tags: inequality

What approach should be taken to solve inequalities similar to the following one?

$x < \sqrt{2 - x}$

p.s. The answer as I have been told is $x < 1$.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that for the inequality to make sense, we need $\sqrt{2-x}$ to exist as a real number and hence we need $2-x \geq 0$. Hence, $x \leq 2$. Now observe that the right hand side is always positive and hence if $x < 0$, then the inequality is trivially satisfied. Hence, let us assume $x \geq 0$. We then have (squaring both sides) $$x^2 < 2 - x \implies x^2 + x - 2 < 0 \implies x^2 + 2x -x -2 <0 \implies (x-1)(x+2) < 0$$
This gives us $-2 < x < 1$. Hence, combining all these, we get that $x<1$.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to figure out for what $x$-values there is equality (if your hint is correct, that should be for $x = 1$, this is pretty easy to check). Then on each side of $1$, check to see what side of the inequality is bigger. You only need to test one value on each side, so checking for $x = 0$ and $x = 2$ should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for showing the approach. I would certainly like to vote up this answer, but cannot because of my low reputation score.